# Remove comma to django-taggit for nice autocomplete

Tags: python, django, django-taggit, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using django-taggit for use tags in some models and django-autocomplete-light for the useful autocomplete.

It's possible to show autocomplete better? Like wordpress tag section.. I want to remove the commas and just press enter to insert tags

Example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtJwu.png

Code at the moment:

**forms.py**

```
from .models import *
from django import forms
from autocomplete_light.contrib.taggit_field import TaggitField, TaggitWidget


class HomepageNewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = TaggitField(widget=TaggitWidget('TagAutocomplete'))

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = HomepageNews
```

**autocomplete_light_registry.py**

```
from taggit.models import Tag
import autocomplete_light.shortcuts as al

al.register(Tag)
```

**models.py**

```
class HomepageNews(models.Model):
    [...]
    tags = TaggableManager()
    [...]
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(HomepageNews)
class HomepageNewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = HomepageNewsForm
    model = HomepageNews
```

Comment: Remove the comma from where ?

Comment: From the inputbox.. I don't want to write tag using tag1, tag2, tag3 but just writing tag1 and press enter, tag2 and press enter.. After enter pressing, the tag is inside a box like as wordpress doing.

Comment: You could override the text autocomplete script then.